# yes/No :Is $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{M_2}({\mathbb{C}) } ?$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given $K=\{ A\in  \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{C}) \mid A\text{ has no real eigenvalues} \}, $

is  $K$ dense in  $\mathbb{M_2}({\mathbb{C}) } ?$

My attempt : I know that set of all invertible  matrix  are dense  so $K$ is  dense in $\mathbb{M_2}({\mathbb{C}) }$.

Is it true?

Comment: Isn't it trivial that eigenvalues of complex matrices are complex?

Comment: i thinks  no , it is not necessary @PaulFrost

Comment: All eigenvalues of $\Bbb M_2(\Bbb C)$ are complex. Do you mean "not real"? Remember, $\Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$.

Comment: ya  i mean  all eigenvalue  are complex but not real@PaulSinclair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $K = \{A\in M_n(\mathbb C): \ A \text{ has no real eigenvalues }\}$ is dense in $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Take a matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Perform [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition): $B = QUQ^{-1}$ with unitary $Q$, $U$ upper triangular. $U$ and $B$ are similar, so the diagonal elements of $U$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ with multiplicity.

If $B$ and $U$ have real eigenvalues, then $U+tiI$ and $B+ tiI=Q(U+tiI)Q^{-1}$   have no real eigenvalues for all but finitely many $t\in \mathbb R$. For $t\to 0$, we have $B+itI \to B$. The matrix $B+itI$ has no real eigenvalues for almost all $t$, which proves the density result.

---

The idea of the prove is to use the density of the 'unreal' numbers $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$ in $\mathbb C$. The Schur decomposition is a convenient form to perturb the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I too quickly wrote an absolutely false reasoning. I was not awake!